Appium screen recording is not working when run through Android studio emulator
I have written one simple login script for Appium, but screen recording is not getting stored in the given folder or else it's not even getting recorded. No issue in the code but not sure why its not getting recorded.
Start Recording - https://app.screencast.com/oMBQxF3e467Kw
Stop Recording - https://app.screencast.com/77WkdrvZBUfgF
